# Navigation bar/menu that has category and child category

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, wordpress

I want to implement a navigation bar that is the same in wordpress, like a menu can have a children as well as the children can have a children, so on and so forth. And when I hover the parent the child will show up.

How can that be implemented? I know that involves CSS and Javascript.

If anyone can give me a good resource with that, it would be a great help!

Thanks! :)

Comment: what about: `li:hover > ul {display: block;}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your answer.

I answered this question myself 
Just for future reference, here's the link where I put my answer: http://elsonsolano.com/coding-navigation-menu-bar-drop-down-subpages/

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need JavaScript.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>Main 1
        <ul>
            <li>Sub1.1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Main 2
         <ul>
            <li>Sub2.1</li>
            <li>Sub2.2</li> 
        </ul> 
    </li>
    <li>Main 3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul li {
     float: left; 
}

ul li ul {
    display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

ul li ul li {
    clear:left;
}
```